# Symfony2 post-update-cmd gives "An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am currently on Symfony2 2.3.7.
When I run the composer update command. In the post-update-cmd a script is run to update symfony2. But it fails:

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.  

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Any idea why this is happening?
I tried to run:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

.. and that runs fine. The following is also working fine:

```
php vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
```

But everytime I try the normal composer update the post script fails.
Running the update with --verbose gives the following:

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.                                                      

Exception trace:
 () at C:\xampp\htdocs\forvaltning\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php:203
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeBuildBootstrap() at C:\xampp\htdocs\forvaltning\vendor\sensio\distribution-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler.php:43
 Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:165
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:138
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:107
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchCommandEvent() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:289
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:118
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:897
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:117
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/Composer/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar:15

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

The composer.json contains:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "jquery/jquery",
            "version": "1.9.1",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js",
                "type": "file"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
    "leafo/lessphp": "0.4.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.*",
    "jquery/jquery": "1.9.*",
    "FortAwesome/Font-Awesome": "3.2.1",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "2.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: running `composer update --verbose` should give a full backtrace for the exception, making it easier (or actually possible in your case) to debug that issue

Comment: Did you tried [this](https://gist.github.com/tobalgists/4108305) ?

Comment: Also, be sure to run `composer --self-update` to update it's own binary...

Comment: Brewal. Yes read the question I clearly state that I had run thoose commands. I have updated the question with the verbose dump.

Comment: Please provide your composer.json file

Comment: @Mantas that is now done :)

Comment: i have same error in empty folder with command `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.4.2`

Comment: It's like something wrong in environment. I have tried on blank Windows 7 with same version php and it works well

Comment: My thought have been on the same ... But I haven't solved the issue yet... I have been running the PHP file directly...

Comment: Please put your topic question on resolve

Comment: @AntoineSubit what do you mean? This question was actually never solved. But I guess it doesn't make much sence anymore since we are past version 2.3.

Comment: mine was a memory issue changing `memory_limit = -1` (unlimited) in php.ini made it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## How to solve install/update Symfony 2 issues

One important Symfony requirement is that the `app/cache` and `app/logs` directories must be writable both by the web server and the command line user.

On Linux and macOS systems, if your web server user is different from your command line user, you need to configure permissions properly to avoid issues. There are several ways to achieve that:

### The most common solution :

In a terminal execute following commands :

```
rm -rf bin
rm -rf vendor
composer install
# or if your didn't install composer
php composer.phar install
```

**It should work now!** For more informations see [Symfony installation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html).

**If you still have this error** : «`An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file`»
It means that you have file permission issue.
See below procedure for solve the problem ↓

### Setting up or Fixing File Permissions :

In a terminal execute following commands :

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*
```

**On macOS** systems, the `chmod` command supports the `+a` flag to define an ACL. Use the following script to determine your web server user and grant the needed permissions:

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
sudo chmod +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
sudo chmod +a "$(whoami) allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

**On most Linux and BSD** distributions don't support `chmod +a`, but do support another utility called `setfacl`. You may need to install `setfacl` and [enable ACL support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs) on your disk partition before using it. Then, use the following script to determine your web server user and grant the needed permissions:

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
# if this doesn't work, try adding `-n` option
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX app/cache app/logs
```

### If none of the previous methods work for you

Change the [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) so that the cache and log directories are group-writable or world-writable (depending if the web server user and the command line user are in the same group or not). To achieve this, put the following line at the beginning of the `app/console`, `web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php` files:

```
umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775
// or
umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

> *Note* : Changing the umask is not thread-safe, so the ACL methods are recommended when they are available.

For more information see official documentation : [Symfony file permissions](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: Sorry I get the same error. The path could not be found and then Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

Comment: @Ronnie Jespersen - I edit my answer. Follow the Setting up or Fixing File Permissions procedure for fix your issue.

Comment: yes I see. It's hard for me to say that this is the answer since I no longer on that codebase but I think you clearly state a lot of options to fix the issue. With the current 13 up-votes I hope its people expressing that it solves their issues so I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I've got the exact same error and I fixed it with this exact procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think remove the folder bundles in the web directory "web/bundles" before running the update. This should solve the assets install problems in post-update-cmd

Comment: Same error i'm afraid... My web/bundles folder is empty. I tried both install and update but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it in two parts. The crux of the problem was bad code on my part that wouldn't specifically apply to someone else, but my method for uncovering the issue might be useful to someone else.

First, I created a temporary file: app/test.php

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

You'll notice that is a slimmed down version of app/autoload.php

Next in my shell, I simply ran:

```
php app/test.php
```

After some trial and error, I discovered that I had an error in a private repo that I had as a requirement in my composer.json file. In my case, and I had a bootstrap file that was calling the very bootstrap.cache.php that we're trying to get composer to create.

Anyway, this method was useful because it output errors that composer install/update would not, even with "--verbose" enabled and temporarily modifying the code to output all errors.

Comment: Hi @Pivot Thanks for your reply.. my problem is specific to me and none of the other developers in the office. I will try your approach as soon as possible and return with the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache with

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

and then try again

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. Even calling

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ "2.3.*"
```

in an empty directory failed.

After all I rebooted and everything is fine again.

Answer (score 0):

this could also caused by an error in some controller, if your code is not clear then you can't update the composer . hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem running `composer.phar install` with Symfony3 on Mac OS (Mavericks) with MAMP: `script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception`.

Solved by updating the PHP version from 5.4 to 5.6. As Symfony runs inside MAMP, I forgot that my system default PHP version is not supported by Symfony3. After the PHP upgrade, the composer run with success.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to use Symfony 3 on a Bluehost, shared hosting, server. 
I first had to find and use the php 5.4 client in order to get composer to run, then I got the same error you did.
[Check the docs here.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html)

> PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.5.9

So you are using a php client that composer supports, and Symfony does not.
Bluehost provides the php client v5.6.24 accessible at `/usr/php/56/bin/php`.

So, using that php executable:

```
/usr/php/56/bin/php ~/my/path/to/composer.phar install
```

I successfully ran "`composer install`" and all of the post-install-cmd's completed with no errors.
This is also the way to call `bin/console` or in your case `app/console` commands.
i.e.

```
## Symfony 2
/usr/php/56/bin/php app/console cache:clear -e prod

## Symfony 3
/usr/php/56/bin/php bin/console cache:clear -e prod
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I had this problem so I have no way of verifying, but it sounds like that might have been the problem. Though i'm pretty sure the require `"php": ">=5.3.3"` was from their documentation meaning I would have the minimum required version of PHP needed to run the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating your composer.json to match the php version you have on your machine

```
"config" : {
    "bin-dir" : "bin",
    "platform" : {
        "php" : "7.0.21" //Update this same as your $> php -v
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had no permissions errors. It had to do with a require() for disabled PHP functions in the **pnctl-event-loop-emitter** library. The composer autoloader was failing hard and crashed the script. The solution was to **enable pcntl_ functions in php.ini**.

The offending file was vendor/composer/../gos/pnctl-event-loop-emitter/src/functions.php

```
; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.^M
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is^M
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.^M
; http://php.net/disable-functions^M
; disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
disable_functions =
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw this error too.  In my case the error stopped when I disabled the APC extension in php.ini.