# Invalid type for path "doctrine_mongodb.connections". Expected array, but got string

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, setter, getter

I am pretty new to coding and this site so im sorry for mistakes i will and/or will not make.

I am trying to generate setters and getters for mongoDB (using symfony 3) but when i type into console

```
php C:\wamp64\www\test\app\console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents MainBundle
```

i get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]                  
  Invalid type for path "doctrine_mongodb.connections". Expected array, but got string
```

Noticed topics about hierarchy on yml and the indentation and  couldnt find the right answer. As i said im pretty new and dont know much about how this sytem works so if anyone have any ideas what the problem could be here please share those with me. 
 this is my config.yml file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@MainBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use layout session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"



    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

doctrine_mongodb:
  connections: default
  default:
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
  default_database: test_database
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2 spaces indentation:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections: default
  default: # <-- here
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
```

and you don't need to specify `default` value for `connections` like that: `connections: default` but instead, it should be an array.

So the valid config should be:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default: # <-- indentation added here
      server: mongodb://localhost:27017
      options: {}
  default_database: test_database
  document_managers:
    default:
      auto_mapping: true
```

See [configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html).

Also, I see you are using 4 spaces indentation in 3/4 of your config file. I would recommend you to use the same indentation everywhere in the file so you won't have any troubles in the future, plus the structure will look more consistent.

Comment: This is something for another question. And it's connected to doctrine.orm configuration.

Comment: @marras so the error is clear. In your `doctrine.orm.layout_entity_manager` service you are trying to inject `doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.layout` service which is not defined in your services configuration file, it doesn't exist, but this is the issue for another question and is not related to this one.

Comment: Ok so I am not quite sure what did the magic, but i found this idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067622/symfony2-post-update-cmd-gives-an-error-occurred-when-generating-the-bootstrap
to remove the /bin and /vendor folders of your project.Then make a composer install (or php composer.phar install if your didn't install composer). In addition i ran `php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` and the whole system seems working just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Error is very clear - just change `doctrine_mongodb.connections` value to `array`.

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:  {}
```

Comment: Didnt help, same error occurs :
`code`[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]                    
  Invalid type for path "doctrine_mongodb.connections.0". Expected array, but got string

Comment: check my updated answer - it must be array but also with parameters inside it.