# ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I recently started learning symfony 2.8 and trying to set up my 1st page on local host. However after configuring my bundle based on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9aQxvEAdcE&list=PLp9j56Yo8a6aWJhLyggonvP7b8vIcYn5Q&index=3

i get this error :

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "doctrine.orm.layout_entity_manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.layout".
```

when trying to open my page with adress localhost/st/web/app_dev.php

The reason I am asking this is that couldnt find anything about this particular problem and have no idea what these services is about. If anyone have any clue what I am doing wrong or why this error occurs please share those with me. I am not adding any code because I am not quite sure which files could be the reason of this error. Thanks in advance

EDITED :

I am creating new symfony project using php storm located in `C:\wamp64\www\st` (enabled symfony plugin and command line tool)

then generating a bundle called MainBundle

I rename `DefaultController.php` in `MainBundle/Controller` to `MainController.php` and change class within it to `MainController`.
Then rename default folder in `app/Resources/views` to `layout`, as well as `base.html.twig` to `layout.html.twig` 
Then filling a twig files with boostrap template

Then change MainController.php into this :

```
<?php

namespace MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route ("/", name="home")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MainBundle:Default:home.html.twig');
    }
}
```

then in `src/Resource/views/Defaul`t change `index.html.twig` into `home.html.twig`

`src/MainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` fill like this :

```
main:
    resource: "@MainBundle/Controller/MainController.php"
    prefix:     /
    type: annotation
```

Adding github project link https://github.com/marras1/st

Comment: What action are you taking to produce this error? Why not dump all your files into a github project and link to it from here? Or try reducing your code to the smallest thing that demonstrates the problem, then post that here. It's much harder to debug your problem without seeing any code.

Comment: @WillSheppard edited question with more details and added github link to post. Hope it is clear anough to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I am not quite sure what did the magic, but i found this idea here: [Symfony2 post-update-cmd gives "An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067622/symfony2-post-update-cmd-gives-an-error-occurred-when-generating-the-bootstrap)
to remove the /bin and /vendor folders of your project.Then make a composer install (or php composer.phar install if your didn't install composer). In addition i ran `php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` and the whole system seems working just fine for now.