# Symfony 2.7: [RuntimeException]An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file

Tags: php, symfony

After clonning a Symfony 2.7 project that I use to develop and install succesfully, when I now run

```
comopser install
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/vendor/sensio/distribution-  bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php:0
>   PHP   2. require_once() /opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/vendor/sensio/distribution-  bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php:56
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening   required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/app/../vendor/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'   (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/app/../vendor:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/app/autoload.php on line 14
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php:0
>   PHP   2. require_once() /opt/lampp/htdocs/IAG/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php:56
>   Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>     [RuntimeException]
>     An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.

I don't know what is really wrong

Comment: Is it possible this is a permissions problem? Can you verify using `sudo composer install` instead?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/22063437/1316350

Comment: Alvin, I use to try sudo composer install but does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067622/symfony2-post-update-cmd-gives-an-error-occurred-when-generating-the-bootstrap